# PHP only show photo in slider if value is not empty

Tags: php, wordpress, string, if-statement, isset

I'm trying to make a slider and **it works perfectly when 3 images** are uploaded in the backend. It doesn't work when there are fewer.

[The slider is a standard Bootstrap slider as seen here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)

[The "the_field('afbeelding')" is from Advanced custom fields WP plugin as seen here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)

In the WP backend a user can upload an image, the_field('afbeelding') will print the url to the image.

For example, if there are only 2 images then it should only show 2 slides.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li> 
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>                  
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>                 
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" >
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="<?php the_field('afbeelding')?>" alt="<?php the_title() ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="<?php the_field('afbeelding_2');?>" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="<?php the_field('afbeelding_3');?>" alt="">
        </div>         
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
       <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
       <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I tried to fix it by changing each item to this:

```
<?php if(isset(the_field('afbeelding_2'))){?>
     <div class="item">
       <img src="<?php the_field('afbeelding_2');?>" alt="">
     </div> 
<?php } ?>
```

But it didn't work...

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Without seeing the code running the carousel we can only guess what the problem is. Want me to guess?

Comment: To expand more on @JayBlanchard comment. It would help us help you if you give us more context/info. Would you also show the code that runs the carousel effect, show what 'the_field(..)' does and explain what 'afbeelding' means?

Comment: @JayBlanchard  My bad and you're totally right. I'll edit the main post to be more clear.

Comment: @David'thebaldginger' I will, i'll edit the main post

Answer (score 2):

you was almost there if you check the reference code for the advanced custom fields which you are using you will find out that if you want to check if the value exists for that field you need to use `get_field()` functions.

I didn't work before with this plugin but i believe `the_field()` is always returning true that's why you need to `get_field()` which return either true if the value exists  or  false  if not and in this case your condition will work as expected .

```
<?php
if (get_field('afbeelding_2')) { ?>
<div class="item">
<img src="<?php the_field('afbeelding_2');?>" alt="">
</div>
<?php }?>
```

[Reference](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)

Comment: Why should the OP "do it this way"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard you are correct i should add more explanation about this one

Comment: @kashalo, Thank you! I'll be able to test it tonight but I just read the documentation and it now seems kind of obvious!

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks for helping out :)